# JSON PATH Field NULL Checking Expression

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a json array like bellow :

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99,
            "likes": 1
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10}
```

I was trying to find all books price which have no **likes** field. Is it possible to find using [Jayway Json Path library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). I am trying something like this `$.store.book[? (@.likes == null)].price` but i don't know whether there is anything like that?

Comment: You can use http://jsonpath.com to validate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This jsonpath expression is correct:

```
$.store.book[?(@.likes == null)].price
```

But you must set `DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL`, for example:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration()
    .addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);

String pricesForBooksWithNoLikes = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json)
    .read("$.store.book[?(@.likes == null)].price");
```

More details [in the docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#options).

Here's a screenshot showing this read working, using the [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/):

[image]